# How to render .md (Markdown) files in local Jekyll install?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I have Jekyll installed on my local machine and have cloned my github pages repo, which contains a README.md file.

Whilst my index.html file renders fine, trying to access the README.md file just results in my browser trying to do a download / save as of the file rather than trying to render it.

What's the issue here? Tried searching to no avail.

Comment: OK let me put it different.  On github.com the readme.me  page displays beautifully if I edit it and upload it works fine.  I want to view that same page locally before uploading.  How would I do that?

Comment: Does the README get rendered as part of the pages site? Or do you mean the README is rendered on the GitHub project page? The later is not part of Pages (or Jekyll).

Comment: As part of the io pages site.  Basically I followed the instructions here : https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

Ok the solution seems to be simple -- when accessing the file in the browser there's no need to specify the file extension. so /README works but /README.md does not.

Hope that helps fellow newbies.

Answer (score 0):

The README is not part of the site, so it will not be rendered.

If you want to see it you can run:

```
kramdown README.md
```

Comment: I'll have take another look tomorrow, all I know is readme.Md is a normal file generated by github pages and on github the io URL displays it fine . But copy it down the local and try to run it using a local jekyll install and it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Chrome installed too, try this:

```
kramdown README.md > README.html && google-chrome README.html
```

This converts the markdown file to an html file and opens it in Google Chrome.